# Producing a more appealing rounded end of line joins

Tags: tikz-pgf

From the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519581/drawing-a-cross-using-only-one-quadrant/519624#519624); I used the following code to draw another cross.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\def\edge{
(.5,.5) to [out=90,in=-90] ++ (0,1.05) to [out=0,in=-90] ++ (.52,.52) to [out=90,in=0] ++ (-.52,.52) to [out=90,in=0] ++ (-.52,.52) to [out=180,in=90] ++ (-.52,-.52) to [out=-180,in=90] ++ (-.52,-.52)  to [out=-90,in=180] ++ (.52,-.52) to [out=-90,in=90] ++ (0,-1.05)}
    \draw[line width=.1cm,blue, fill=blue!40!white, opacity=.6] (.5,.5) foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}{[rotate=\i] -- \edge} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I noticed that using `[line join=round, line cap=round]` produced an extended end of lines. Omitting this option produced less appealing line joins.

How can `line join=round` be used to produce rounded ends of lines, without producing the extended parts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple calculation error in your code. Indeed, the path starts at the point `(.5,.5)` but your semicircles have a radius of `.52`, which does **not end** the first quarter of the cross at the coordinate point `(-.5,.5)`. 
By replacing the radius of `.52` by `.5`, the problem is solved. Notice that I have slightly simplified your code by removing some unnecessary `to` operations.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\def\edge{
(.5,.5) -- ++ (0,1.05) to [out=0,in=-90] ++ (.5,.5) to [out=90,in=0] ++ (-.5,.5) to [out=90,in=0] ++ (-.5,.5) to [out=180,in=90] ++ (-.5,-.5) to [out=-180,in=90] ++ (-.5,-.5)  to [out=-90,in=180] ++ (.5,-.5) -- ++ (0,-1.05)}
\draw[line width=.1cm,blue, fill=blue!40!white, opacity=.6] (.5,.5) foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}{[rotate=\i] -- \edge}--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

Your code for the `\edge` can be shortened *very* much, and this shortening automatically also fixes the issue. Also you probably want to use a `transparency group` in order to avoid that the boundary has two colors.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\def\edge{
(.5,.5) -- ++ (0,1.05)foreach \j in {0,90,180}  {to [out=\j,in=\j,looseness=1.6] ++ (\j+90:1)}}
\begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=.6]
\draw[line width=.1cm,blue, fill=blue!40!white] (.5,.5) foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}{[rotate=\i] -- \edge} -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: @Hany It is my pleasure (and it wasn't too difficult since after all I was involved in the creation of the original `\edge` command ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Handmade shifts are evil! I'm sure there must be a most suitable solution (more maintainable) using labeling of nodes, but I'm not familiar enough with `tikz` to draw such a solution. Meanwhile, you can try:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\def\edge{
(.5,.5) to [out=90,in=-90] ++ (0,1.05) to [out=0,in=-90] ++ (.5,.5) to [out=90,in=0] ++ (-.5,.5) to [out=90,in=0] ++ (-.5,.5) to [out=180,in=90] ++ (-.5,-.5) to [out=-180,in=90] ++ (-.5,-.5)  to [out=-90,in=180] ++ (.5,-.5) to [out=-90,in=90] ++ (0,-1.05)}
    \draw[line width=.1cm,blue, fill=blue!40!white, opacity=.6] (.5,.5) foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}{[rotate=\i] -- \edge} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which eliminates the overlaps.
[image]