# Modifying one part of a \foreach loop drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

From the answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519581/drawing-a-cross-using-only-one-quadrant/519624#519624) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519783/producing-a-more-appealing-rounded-end-of-line-joins) questions;

I used the following code to draw a cross.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Cross 3}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\def\edge{
(.5,.5) -- ++ (0,1.05) to [out=0,in=-90] ++ (.5,.5) to [out=90,in=0] ++ (-.5,.5) to [out=90,in=0] ++ (-.5,.5) to [out=180,in=90] ++ (-.5,-.5) to [out=-180,in=90] ++ (-.5,-.5)  to [out=-90,in=180] ++ (.5,-.5) -- ++ (0,-1.05)}
\draw[line width=.16cm,blue!60!black, fill=blue!80!black] (.5,.5) foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}{[rotate=\i] -- \edge} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to modify one part of the `\foreach` loop to produce the following drawings.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. You only need to use `\ifnum`. This works especially smoothly when you use the shortened `\edge` from my previous answer, which avoids unnecessary repetition. In more detail, let's define

```
\def\edge{
(.5,.5) -- ++ \ifnum\i=180 (0,2.5) \else (0,1.05)\fi
foreach \j in {0,90,180}  {to [out=\j,in=\j,looseness=1.6] ++ (\j+90:1)}
}
```

Here you see that if `\i` equals 180, there will be a line of length `2.5` whereas for all other `\i` it is `1.05` units long.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Cross 3}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\def\edge{
(.5,.5) -- ++ \ifnum\i=180 (0,2.5) \else (0,1.05)\fi
foreach \j in {0,90,180}  {to [out=\j,in=\j,looseness=1.6] ++ (\j+90:1)}
}
\draw[line width=.16cm,blue!60!black, fill=blue!80!black] (.5,.5)
 foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}{[rotate=\i] -- \edge} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Cross 3}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\def\edge{
(.5,.5) -- ++ \ifnum\i=180 (0,2.5)to[out=90,in=90] ++ (-1,0) \else (0,1.05)
foreach \j in {0,90,180}  {to [out=\j,in=\j] ++ (\j+90:1)} \fi
}

\draw[line width=.16cm,blue!60!black, fill=blue!80!black,looseness=1.6] 
(.5,.5)
 foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}{[rotate=\i] -- \edge} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Schrödinger's cat  for your kind interest.