# Correction of calculation error to produce a more appealing rounded end of line joins

Tags: tikz-pgf

From the answers to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519783/producing-a-more-appealing-rounded-end-of-line-joins/519838#519838) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519581/drawing-a-cross-using-only-one-quadrant?noredirect=1#comment1314067_519581) questions,
I used the following code to draw a cross, which produced an extended rounded corners. I understood that this is due to a calculation error, but I could not figure out which measures to adjust.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % suppress navigation bar
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Coptic Cross original final (question applied)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\def\edge{
(.5,.5) to [out=90,in=-160] ++ (1,1.45) to [out=130,in=0] ++ (-1,.35) to [out=90,in=-20] ++ (-.5,.8) to [out=-160,in=90] ++ (-.5,-.8) to [out=180,in=50] ++ (-1,-.35) to [out=-20,in=90] ++ (1,-1.45)}
\draw[line width=.1cm,blue, fill=blue!40!white, opacity=.6, rounded corners=.1cm] (.5,.5) foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}{[rotate=\i] -- \edge} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem does not come from a calculation error, but from the fact that you use rounded corners and paths of length 0. Just get rid of those paths.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % suppress navigation bar
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Coptic Cross original final (question applied)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\def\edge{
(.5,.6) to [out=90,in=-160] ++ (1,1.45) to [out=130,in=0] ++ (-1,.35) to
[out=90,in=-20] ++ (-.5,.8) to [out=-160,in=90] ++ (-.5,-.8) to [out=180,in=50]
++ (-1,-.35) to [out=-20,in=90] ++ (1,-1.45)}
\draw[line width=.1cm,blue, fill=blue!40!white, opacity=.6, rounded
corners=.1cm] (.5,.6) foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}{[rotate=\i] -- \edge} --
cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way to go is to switch the rounded corners off and on as needed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % suppress navigation bar
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Coptic Cross original final (question applied)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\def\edge{
(0,3.1) to [out=-160,in=90] ++ (-.5,-.8) 
[rounded corners=2pt]
 to [out=180,in=50] ++ (-1,-.35) 
 to [out=-20,in=90] ++ (1,-1.45)
 to [out=180,in=-70] ++ (-1.45,1) 
 to [out=220,in=90] ++ (-.35,-1) [sharp corners]
 to [out=180,in=70] ++ (-.8,-.5)
}
\draw[line width=.1cm,blue, fill=blue!40!white, opacity=.6] 
(0,3.1) foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}{[rotate=\i] -- \edge} --
cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hany You're welcome!