# Drawing Spirograph patterns using \foreach loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I used the following code from the answer to
[this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522881/combining-spirograph-code-with-nested-multiple-foreach-loop), to draw a Spirograph pattern

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/spiro/.style={code={
\tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}} 
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions]
 plot[variable=\t,domain=0:2*pi*\pv{nRotations}, samples=90*\pv{nRotations}+1, smooth cycle]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
);
}},
spiro/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1,nRotations/.initial=1}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.2mm]
\foreach \i/\clr in {5/blue,10/blue,15/blue,20/blue,25/blue,30/blue,35/blue,40/blue,45/blue,50/green,55/green,60/green,65/green,70/green,75/green,80/green,85/green,90/green,95/orange,100/orange,105/orange,110/orange,115/orange,120/orange,125/orange,130/orange,135/orange,140/purple,145/purple,150/purple,155/purple,160/purple,165/purple,170/purple,175/purple,180/purple}
{
(0,0) \pic[draw=\clr,rotate=\i,scale=.4]{spiro={R=10.5,r=-5.25,p=3,nRotations=1}};
}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried using the following code to simplify repeating each rotation angle, but something is not right!

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.2mm]
\foreach \b in {5,10,...,45}
\foreach \g in {50,55,...,90}
\foreach \o in {95,100,...,135}
\foreach \p in {140,145,...,180}
\foreach \i/\clr in {\b/blue,\g/green,\o/orange,\p/purple}
{
(0,0) \pic[draw=\clr,rotate=\i,scale=.4]{spiro={R=10.5,r=-5.25,p=3,nRotations=1}};
}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
```

I also tried to apply the code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521165/modifying-foreach-loop-to-make-first-loop-overlaps-last-one) to avoid overlapping tha last pattern over the older ones to produce the following drawing (using the option fill=\clr!40) but I could not figure out how to apply it.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/spiro/.style={code={
\tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}} 
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions]
 plot[variable=\t,domain=0:2*pi*\pv{nRotations}, samples=90*\pv{nRotations}+1, smooth cycle]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
);
}},
spiro/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1,nRotations/.initial=1}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.2mm]
\path foreach \clr [count=\X starting from 0] in {blue,green,orange,purple}
{foreach \Y in {1,...,9}
{(0,0) pic[draw=\clr,rotate=45*\X+5*\Y,scale=.4]{spiro={R=10.5,r=-5.25,p=3,nRotations=1}}
}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This loops over the colors and draws for each color the graph in 9 versions, relatively rotated by 5 degrees each. Please also notice that `(0,0)` in your code had no effect, and that I slightly change the `foreach`s to be in the path.

One may also want to interpolate between the colors.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/spiro/.style={code={
\tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}} 
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions]
 plot[variable=\t,domain=0:2*pi*\pv{nRotations}, samples=90*\pv{nRotations}+1, smooth cycle]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
);
}},
spiro/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1,nRotations/.initial=1}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.2mm]
\path foreach \clr [count=\X starting from 0,
    remember=\clr as \lastclr (initially purple)] in {blue,green,orange,purple}
{foreach \Y [evaluate=\Y as \mycf using {int(100*\Y/9)}] in {1,...,9}
{(0,0) pic[draw=\clr!\mycf!\lastclr,rotate=45*\X+5*\Y-22.5,scale=.4]{spiro={R=10.5,r=-5.25,p=3,nRotations=1}}
}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: You can also produce filled graphs. However, in this case your definition may not be optimal. So I changed that.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/spiro/.style={code={
\tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}} 
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions]
 plot[variable=\t,domain=pi/2:3*pi/2, samples=31, smooth]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
);
}},
spiro path/.code={\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}}
\tikzset{insert path={
plot[trig format=rad,variable=\t,domain=pi/2:3*pi/2, samples=31,
smooth,domain=pi:pi/2]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
) 
|- (\pv{R}+\pv{r}+\pv{p},-\pv{R}-\pv{r}-\pv{p})
-- 
(\pv{R}+\pv{r}+\pv{p},\pv{R}+\pv{r}+\pv{p})  --
(-\pv{R}-\pv{r}-\pv{p},\pv{R}+\pv{r}+\pv{p})
--  cycle
}}},
spiro/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.2mm,spiro/.cd,R=10.5,r=-5.25,p=3]
\begin{scope}
\foreach\Z in {0,1}
{\foreach \clr [count=\X starting from 0] in {blue,green,orange,purple}
{\foreach \Y in {1,...,9}
{\ifnum\Z\X\Y=102
 \clip[scale=.4,rotate=5,spiro path];
\fi
\pic[draw=\clr,rotate=45*\X+5*\Y+\Z*180,scale=.4,fill=\clr!40]{spiro};
}}}
\end{scope}
\fill[white] circle[radius={0.4*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/R}+
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/r}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/p})}];
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With color interpolation it does not look too bad IMHO.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/spiro/.style={code={
\tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}} 
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions]
 plot[variable=\t,domain=pi/2:3*pi/2, samples=31, smooth]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
);
}},
spiro path/.code={\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}}
\tikzset{insert path={
plot[trig format=rad,variable=\t,domain=pi/2:3*pi/2, samples=31,
smooth,domain=pi:pi/2]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
) 
|- (\pv{R}+\pv{r}+\pv{p},-\pv{R}-\pv{r}-\pv{p})
-- 
(\pv{R}+\pv{r}+\pv{p},\pv{R}+\pv{r}+\pv{p})  --
(-\pv{R}-\pv{r}-\pv{p},\pv{R}+\pv{r}+\pv{p})
--  cycle
}}},
spiro/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.2mm,spiro/.cd,R=10.5,r=-5.25,p=3]
\foreach\Z in {0,1}
{\foreach \clr [count=\X starting from 0,
    remember=\clr as \lastclr (initially purple)] in {blue,green,orange,purple}
{\foreach \Y [evaluate=\Y as \mycf using {int(100*\Y/9)}] in {1,...,9}
{\ifnum\Z\X\Y=102
 \clip[scale=.4,rotate=5,spiro path];
\fi
\pic[draw=\clr!\mycf!\lastclr,rotate=45*\X+5*\Y+\Z*180,scale=.4,fill=\clr!\mycf!\lastclr!40]{spiro};
}}}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about solving the filling issue by applying your code in the answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521165/modifying-foreach-loop-to-make-first-loop-overlaps-last-one  to avoid overlapping the last pattern over the previous ones! I could not figure out how to apply it.

Comment: @Hany Sorry, I did not read this part of the question in that way, also because there is no code. However, I also do not understand how the target output should look like. What would you like to do with the inner circle?

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat Thank you very much for your answers. This is what I had in mind. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmved.png  Your answers are as close as possible.

Comment: @Hany You're welcome! You can just add a white disk to achieve this.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat Thank you very very much for your concern. I appreciate very much your answers. Just one comment; how to add a disk!

Comment: @Hany Added it.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat Thank you very much.