# How to get the last circle behind the first one?

Tags: tikz-pgf

As the question says, how to get the last circle behind the first one in the following picture?
The MWE is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{20}
  \def\a{360/\n}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}{
    \draw[fill=yellow] (\i*\a:2) circle [radius=1];
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The picture to be corrected.]

Comment: I do not know how to do it in tikz, but you can instead of filling and drawing the circles create a path that consists of the little piece you want to have, and draw it. In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fowBW.png) I made the little piece green. In MetaPost (that I used) the piece is simply made by using `buildcycle`, but as mentioned, I do not know how to do it in tikz. But I'm sure someone else will help with that.

Comment: Use a clip probably. Related: [tikz pgf - Modifying \foreach loop to make first loop overlaps last one - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521165/modifying-foreach-loop-to-make-first-loop-overlaps-last-one)

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE:**
This is a more configurable solution, and easier in the maths department too.

For this one I made two `\pics`, one for the 'petals' and another for the 'flower' that repeats and rotate the petals.

Like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\tikzset
{
  pics/petal/.style 2 args={% #1 = radius, #2 = distance to the next petal
    code={
      \pgfmathsetmacro\half{0.5*#2}
      \ifdim\half pt<#1 pt % if the petals intersect
        \pgfmathsetmacro\aa{acos(\half/#1)}
        \path[pic actions] (\aa:#1) arc (\aa:360-\aa:#1) arc (180+\aa:180-\aa:#1);
      \else % if the petals don't intersect
        \draw[pic actions] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];
      \fi
    }},
  pics/flower/.style n args={3}{% #1 = flower radius, #2 = petal radius, #3 = number of petals
    code={
      \pgfmathsetmacro\dd{#1*sqrt(2*(1-cos(360/#3))} % distance between petals
      \foreach\i in {1,...,#3}
        \pic[draw,fill,rotate=180/#3+360*\i/#3+90] at (360*\i/#3:#1) {petal={#2}{\dd}};
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
\foreach\i in {1,...,4}
  \pic[fill=green!20,rotate=90*\i+180] at (90*\i:4) {petal={1}{1}};
\pic[draw=red ,fill=red!20]  {flower={3}{1}{12}};
\pic[draw=blue,fill=blue!10] {flower={3}{0.2}{4}};
\pic[draw=blue,fill=blue!30] {flower={1}{0.2}{20}};
\foreach\i in {1,...,12}
  \pic[fill=yellow,rotate=30*\i] at (30*\i:3) {flower={0.4}{0.1}{7}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**INITIAL ANSWER:**

I'm creating a `\pic` that draws only the visible part of the circle (the same idea that mickep proposes, I think). Then I draw it and rotate each time.

It needs to compute a couple of angles using the cosine theorem (for example).

This is my solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{20}
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{360/\n}
\pgfmathsetmacro\aa{acos(4*cos(\a)-3)} % some other angles
\pgfmathsetmacro\bb{90-0.5*\aa}        % obtained from the
\pgfmathsetmacro\cc{0.5*\aa-0.5*\a}    % cosine theorem
\tikzset
{% a pic (like a crescent moon)
  pics/moon/.style={
    code={
      \path[pic actions] (0:2) ++ (180-\cc:1) arc (180-\cc:540-\cc-2*\bb:1) arc (\a-180+\cc+2*\bb:\a-180+\cc:1);
    }},
}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
  \pic[draw,fill=yellow,rotate=\a*\i] (\a*\i:2) {moon};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, changing

```
\def\n{8}
....
\pic[draw=red,thick,fill=orange!30,rotate=\a*\i] (\a*\i:2) {moon};
....
```

[image]

Comment: Certainly gets the job done :) Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is what I did (but perhaps with less manual calculations). I can add the code for what I did, it might help someone.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{20}
\def\a{360/\n}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
   \draw[fill=yellow] (\i*\a:2) circle[radius=1];
\clip (0,-3) rectangle (3,3);
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
   \draw[fill=yellow] ({int(\i-\n/2)*\a}:2) circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Donut of filled circles]

Answer (score 4):

Since you now how a tikz answer that works for you, here is the code that I used to draw the image in my comment:

```
\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
numeric N ; N := 20 ;
path c[] ;
c[1] := fullcircle rotated 180 scaled 2cm yshifted 2cm ;
c[2] := reverse c[1] rotated (360/N) ;
c[3] := buildcycle(c[1],c[2]) ;

for i = 0 upto N - 1:
  fill c[3] rotated (i*360/N) withcolor yellow ;
  draw c[3] rotated (i*360/N) ;
endfor

fill c[3] withcolor darkgreen ;
draw c[3] withcolor darkred ;
\stopMPpage
```

A few comments:

1. The last fill and draw of course only shows the green and red piece that is used.
2. The `rotated 180` and `reverse` are there only so that `buildcycle` will choose the right piece.

[image: overlapping disks]

I notice that the `yellow` color is different in tikz and MetaPost. That was new to me.