# Simplifying multiple \foreach loops

Tags: tikz-pgf

I used the following code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520840/using-rounded-corners-produces-an-extra-end-of-line-corner/520842#520842), (using a loop method) to draw a concentric figure.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Spiro using loop}%rounded corners solution 1
\vskip -.6cm
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=2]%transparency group,opacity=.4, 
\draw[line width=.2cm,blue!80!black, fill=blue, looseness=1] 
(0,-2.2) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
{[rotate=\X] -- (0,-2.2) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to [out=60,in=-150] ++ (1.9,1.9) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\draw[line width=.2cm,blue, fill=blue!80!white, looseness=1] 
(0,-2) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
{[rotate=\X] -- (0,-2) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to [out=60,in=-150] ++ (1.7,1.7) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\draw[line width=.2cm,blue!80!white, fill=blue!70!white, looseness=1] 
(0,-1.8) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
{[rotate=\X] -- (0,-1.8) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to [out=60,in=-150] ++ (1.5,1.5) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\draw[line width=.2cm,blue!70!white, fill=blue!60!white, looseness=1] 
(0,-1.6) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
{[rotate=\X] -- (0,-1.6) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to [out=60,in=-150] ++ (1.3,1.3) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\draw[line width=.2cm,blue!60!white, fill=blue!50!white, looseness=1] 
(0,-1.4) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
{[rotate=\X] -- (0,-1.4) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to [out=60,in=-150] ++ (1.1,1.1) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\draw[line width=.2cm,blue!50!white, fill=blue!40!white, looseness=1] 
(0,-1.2) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
{[rotate=\X] -- (0,-1.2) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to [out=60,in=-150] ++ (.9,.9) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\draw[line width=.2cm,blue!40!white, fill=blue!30!white, looseness=1] 
(0,-1.) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
{[rotate=\X] -- (0,-1.) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to [out=60,in=-150] ++ (.7,.7) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\draw[line width=.2cm,blue!30!white, fill=blue!20!white, looseness=1] 
(0,-.8) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
{[rotate=\X] -- (0,-.8) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to [out=60,in=-150] ++ (.5,.5) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\draw[line width=.2cm,blue!20!white, fill=blue!10!white, looseness=1] 
(0,-.6) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
{[rotate=\X] -- (0,-.6) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to [out=60,in=-150] ++ (.3,.3) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\draw[line width=.2cm,blue!10!white, fill=blue!0!white, looseness=1] 
(0,-.4) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
{[rotate=\X] -- (0,-.4) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to [out=60,in=-150] ++ (.1,.1) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;
\end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to simplify this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this effect also with scale. It does not match your picture precisely, but that's on purpose because I think the arcs of the effective corners are also to be scaled.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Spirifankerln}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/spiro/.style={code={
 \draw[line width=.1cm,looseness=1,pic actions]
  (0,-2) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
  {[rotate=\X] -- (0,-2) to[out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to[out=60,in=-150] ++ (1.7,1.7)
  to[out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)} -- cycle;}}]
\foreach \X in {100,90,...,0}
{\pic[draw=blue!\X,fill=blue!\X,scale={1.8*(\X+10)/100}]{spiro};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does Spirifankerln mean!

Comment: @Hany This is impossible to translate precisely. Maybe something like decorations.

Answer (score 10):

Find the pattern, and use nested loops.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Spiro using loop}
\vskip -.6cm
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,.2,.4,...,1.8} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\firstcolor{scalar(100-\i*50)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\secondcolor{scalar(90-\i*50)}
    \begin{scope}[scale=2]
      \draw [
        line width=.2cm,color/.expanded=blue!\firstcolor!white,
        fill/.expanded=blue!\secondcolor!white, looseness=1
      ] (0,-2.2+\i) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270} {
        [rotate=\X] -- (0,-2.2+\i) to [out=0,in=-120] ++ (0.2,0.1) to 
        [out=60,in=-150] ++ (1.9-\i,1.9-\i) to [out=30,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)
      } -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is as good as Schrödinger's cat answer. I could not decide which one to accept, but I found that Schrödinger's cat answer is more easily editable for me.