# Simplifying and editing \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I used the following code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521189/simplifying-multiple-foreach-loops)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Spirifankerln using scale}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/spiro/.style={code={
 \draw[line width=.1cm,looseness=1,pic actions]
  (0,-2) foreach \X in {0,90,180,270}
  {[rotate=\X]
 -- (0,-2)% node {1}
 to[out=0,in=-90] ++ (0.2,0.1)% node {2}
 to[out=90,in=-180] ++ (1.7,1.7)% node {3}
 to[out=0,in=-90] ++ (0.1,0.2)% node[red] {4}
} -- cycle;}}]
\pic[draw=orange!100,fill=orange!40,scale=2, rotate=11.25]{spiro};
\pic[draw=orange!100,fill=orange!40,scale=2, rotate=-11.25]{spiro};
\pic[draw=orange!100,fill=orange!40,scale=2, rotate=33.75]{spiro};
\pic[draw=orange!100,fill=orange!40,scale=2, rotate=-33.75]{spiro};
\pic[draw=brown!100,fill=brown!40,scale=2, rotate=-22.5]{spiro};
\pic[draw=brown!100,fill=brown!40,scale=2, rotate=22.5]{spiro};
\pic[draw=red!100,fill=red!40,scale=2, rotate=45]{spiro};
\pic[draw=purple!100,fill=purple!40,scale=2]{spiro};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to simplify it, and how to make the corners spiky, resembling the following drawing.

[image]

Comment: It seems that you did not understand the basic principle of TikZ, so you get stuck several times, and just ask many many questions. It is more efficient if you study pgfmanual carefully. Just ignore my advice if you don’t like!

Comment: @Black Mild Thank you for your advice. I am not good at programming, and unfortunately I have a limited time for studying pgf. I will try to spare sometime to take your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to redraw the `pic`. As your colours don't really have a pattern, there is little to simplify.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Spirifankerln using scale}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/spiro/.style={code={
  \draw[line width=.1cm,looseness=1,pic actions]
    (0,-2) arc (180:90:2) arc (270:180:2) arc (360:270:2) arc (90:0:2);
  }
}]
  \foreach \i in {-33.75,-11.25,11.25,33.75}
    \pic[draw=orange!100,fill=orange!40,scale=2,rotate=\i]{spiro};
  \pic[draw=brown!100,fill=brown!40,scale=2, rotate=-22.5]{spiro};
  \pic[draw=brown!100,fill=brown!40,scale=2, rotate=22.5]{spiro};
  \pic[draw=red!100,fill=red!40,scale=2, rotate=45]{spiro};
  \pic[draw=purple!100,fill=purple!40,scale=2]{spiro};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Add everything to a loop (note that the order matters!).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Spirifankerln using scale}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/spiro/.style={code={
  \draw[line width=.1cm,looseness=1,pic actions]
    (0,-2) arc (180:90:2) arc (270:180:2) arc (360:270:2) arc (90:0:2);
  }
}]
  \foreach \i/\clr in {3/orange,1/orange,2/brown,4/red,0/purple} {
    \pic[draw/.expanded=\clr!100,fill/.expanded=\clr!40,scale=2,rotate=\i*11.25]{spiro};
    \pic[draw/.expanded=\clr!100,fill/.expanded=\clr!40,scale=2,rotate=-\i*11.25]{spiro};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(same output as above)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can`t the \foreach loops be combined in one, nesting the colour change.

Comment: @Hany `\foreach` version added

Comment: Thank you for your time and concern.

Comment: @Hany Anything left to improve?

Comment: Thank you very much.