# Modifying \foreach loop to include a nested drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Using the following code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521276/simplifying-and-editing-foreach-loop); how can circles be nested on each spike with colours match those of the individual drawings.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{spiro arcs}%Spirifankerln using scale Fractal solution simple-
\definecolor{camel}{rgb}{0.76, 0.6, 0.42}
\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}
\definecolor{burlywood}{rgb}{0.87, 0.72, 0.53}
\definecolor{fawn}{rgb}{0.9, 0.67, 0.44}
\definecolor{lighttaupe}{rgb}{0.7, 0.55, 0.43}
\definecolor{palebrown}{rgb}{0.6, 0.46, 0.33}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/spiro/.style={code={
  \draw[line width=.04cm,looseness=1,pic actions]
    (0,-2) node [circle, draw, blue, fill=blue!40!white, scale=0.2]{} arc (180:90:2) arc (270:180:2) arc (360:270:2) arc (90:0:2);
  }
}]
  \foreach \i/\clr in {1/apricot, 3/apricot, 5/apricot, 7/apricot, 9/apricot, 11/apricot, 13/apricot, 15/apricot, 2/burlywood, 6/burlywood, 10/burlywood, 14/burlywood, 12/fawn, 4/fawn, 8/camel, 16/lighttaupe, 0/palebrown}
 {
    \pic[draw/.expanded=\clr!100,fill/.expanded=\clr!60,scale=2,rotate=\i*2.8125]{spiro};
    \pic[draw/.expanded=\clr!100,fill/.expanded=\clr!60,scale=2,rotate=-\i*2.8125]{spiro};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have everything that you need already in place. The main issue is that you are putting the circles only after the first set of spikes in each quadrant. To get circles on every spike you need to add `\node` commands after each arc, except for the last one.

You can cater for the changing colours by passing the current colour `\clr` to the spiro pic as a parameter. With these changes your code produces:

[image]

As there are now many nodes I have separated the style for these nodes into a another `dot/.style`, which ultimately receives the current colour `\clr` as its `#1` parameter. Here is the modified code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{spiro arcs}%Spirifankerln using scale Fractal solution simple-
\definecolor{camel}{rgb}{0.76, 0.6, 0.42}
\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}
\definecolor{burlywood}{rgb}{0.87, 0.72, 0.53}
\definecolor{fawn}{rgb}{0.9, 0.67, 0.44}
\definecolor{lighttaupe}{rgb}{0.7, 0.55, 0.43}
\definecolor{palebrown}{rgb}{0.6, 0.46, 0.33}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={circle, draw=#1, fill=#1!60, scale=0.2},
  pics/spiro/.style={code={
  \draw[line width=.04cm,looseness=1,pic actions]
  (0,-2) node [dot=#1]{} arc (180:90:2) node[dot=#1]{}  arc (270:180:2) node[dot=#1]{}  arc (360:270:2) node[dot=#1]{} arc (90:0:2);
  }
}]
  \foreach \i/\clr in {1/apricot, 3/apricot, 5/apricot, 7/apricot, 9/apricot, 11/apricot, 13/apricot, 15/apricot, 2/burlywood, 6/burlywood, 10/burlywood, 14/burlywood, 12/fawn, 4/fawn, 8/camel, 16/lighttaupe, 0/palebrown}
 {
    \pic[draw=\clr!100,fill=\clr!60,scale=2,rotate=\i*2.8125]{spiro=\clr};
    \pic[draw=\clr!100,fill=\clr!60,scale=2,rotate=-\i*2.8125]{spiro=\clr};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Finally, note that it is necessary to add `fragile` to the parameters for the `frame` environment, otherwise you will get compilation errors. I have also removed the `.expanded` handlers as they are not necessary. You could also simplify the `\foreach` command by removing the `\i` and calculating the rotation but as it works this is only of aesthetic coding value:)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

A bit similar to Andrew's answer but making the circles part of the `pic`. That is, I replaced

```
(0,-2) node [circle, draw, blue, fill=blue!40!white, scale=0.2]{}
```

by

```
foreach \X in {0,90,180,270} {(\X:2) node [circle, draw, scale=0.2]{}}
```

I agree with Andrew that `/.expanded` is not needed here.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{spiro arcs}%Spirifankerln using scale Fractal solution simple-
\definecolor{camel}{rgb}{0.76, 0.6, 0.42}
\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}
\definecolor{burlywood}{rgb}{0.87, 0.72, 0.53}
\definecolor{fawn}{rgb}{0.9, 0.67, 0.44}
\definecolor{lighttaupe}{rgb}{0.7, 0.55, 0.43}
\definecolor{palebrown}{rgb}{0.6, 0.46, 0.33}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/spiro/.style={code={
  \draw[line width=.04cm,looseness=1,pic actions]
    foreach \X in {0,90,180,270} {(\X:2) node [circle, draw, scale=0.2]{}} 
    arc (180:90:2) arc (270:180:2) arc (360:270:2) arc (90:0:2);
  }
}]
  \foreach \i/\clr in {1/apricot, 3/apricot, 5/apricot, 7/apricot, 9/apricot, 11/apricot, 13/apricot, 15/apricot, 2/burlywood, 6/burlywood, 10/burlywood, 14/burlywood, 12/fawn, 4/fawn, 8/camel, 16/lighttaupe, 0/palebrown}
 {
    \pic[draw=\clr!100,fill=\clr!60,scale=2,rotate=\i*2.8125]{spiro};
    \pic[draw=\clr!100,fill=\clr!60,scale=2,rotate=-\i*2.8125]{spiro};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I can not accept both yours and Andrew's answers.