# Combining Spirograph code with nested multiple \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I used the following code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522755/combining-spirograph-code-with-foreach-loop) to combine scale with colour and rotate changes

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/spiro/.style={code={
\tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}} 
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions]
 plot[variable=\t,domain=0:2*pi*\pv{nRotations}, samples=90*\pv{nRotations}+1, smooth cycle] 
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
);
}},
spiro/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1,nRotations/.initial=1}
\begin{frame}[t] 
\frametitle{Spiro`6,-1.5,1`- - foreach} 
\begin{center}
\vskip -.8cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.06cm]
\foreach \scl/\clr in {.8/10,.6/30,.4/50,.2/70} 
{
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color/.expanded=blue!\clr,scale=\scl]{spiro}; 
}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t] 
\frametitle{Spiro`6,-1.5,1`- foreach} 
\begin{center}
\vskip -.8cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.06cm]
\foreach \scl/\clr/\clra in {.8/100/80,.7/80/70,.6/70/60,.5/60/50,.4/50/40,.3/40/30,.2/30/20,.1/20/10} 
%    \foreach \scl/\clr/\clra/\clrb in {.8/100/90/80,.7/90/80/70,.6/80/70/60,.5/70/60/50,.4/60/50/40,.3/50/40/30,.2/40/30/20,.1/30/20/10} 
{
(0,0) \pic[draw/.expanded=blue!\clr,fill/.expanded=blue!\clra,scale=\scl]{spiro}; 
%    (0,0) \pic[draw/.expanded=blue!\clr,outer color/.expanded=blue!\clra,inner color/.expanded=blue!\clrb,scale=\scl]{spiro}; 
}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t] 
\frametitle{Spiro`6,-1.5,1`- foreach} 
\begin{center}
\vskip -.8cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.06cm]
\foreach \scl/\rotate/\clr/\clra in {.8/0/100/80,.7/10/80/70,.6/20/70/60,.5/30/60/50,.4/40/50/40,.3/50/40/30,.2/60/30/20,.1/70/20/10} 
{
(0,0) \pic[draw/.expanded=blue!\clr,fill/.expanded=blue!\clra,scale=\scl,rotate/.expanded=\rotate]{spiro}; 
}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

but I could not figure out how to apply it for the following code:

change in scale with both draw and fill colours with rotation

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Spiro`6,-1.5,1`- - - -}
\begin{center}
\vskip -1.cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.8mm]
\draw
(0,0) pic[scale=.8, purple!80, rotate=0, fill=purple!60]{spiro}
(0,0) pic[scale=.7, red!80, rotate=10, fill=red!60]{spiro}
(0,0) pic[scale=.6, orange!80, rotate=20, fill=orange!60]{spiro}
(0,0) pic[scale=.5, yellow!80, rotate=30, fill=yellow!60]{spiro}
(0,0) pic[scale=.4, green!80, rotate=40, fill=green!60]{spiro}
(0,0) pic[scale=.3, cyan!80, rotate=50, fill=cyan!60]{spiro}
(0,0) pic[scale=.2, blue!80, rotate=60, fill=blue!60]{spiro}
(0,0) pic[scale=.1, violet!80, rotate=70, fill=violet!60]{spiro}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to loop over the colors, the scales and rotation angles can be derived from a counter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/spiro/.style={code={
\tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}} 
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions]
 plot[variable=\t,domain=0:2*pi*\pv{nRotations}, samples=90*\pv{nRotations}+1, smooth cycle] 
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
);
}},
spiro/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1,nRotations/.initial=1}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Spiro`6,-1.5,1`- foreach}
\begin{center}
\vskip -1.cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.8mm]
\draw foreach \Col [count=\Y starting from 0] 
    in {purple,red,orange,yellow,green,cyan,blue,violet}
    {pic[scale=.8-0.1*\Y, \Col!80, rotate=\Y*10, fill=\Col!60]{spiro}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Are my codes for the other drawings good; or can they be made better.

Comment: @Hany I think they are very good.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat Thank you very much for all your answers and comments.

Comment: @Hany You are very welcome!

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat I am sorry to bother you again. I am just trying to understand your code. What does  {dx} stand for

Comment: @Hany `dx` is the distance between two points at which the samples are taken. If you *decrease* `dx`, you get *more* plot points.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat Thank you for your time and concern.