# Shifting the whole Spirograph drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I used the following code, from the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522755/combining-spirograph-code-with-foreach-loop) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521276/simplifying-and-editing-foreach-loop?noredirect=1&lq=1), to draw a Spirograph figure

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/spiro/.style={code={
\tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}} 
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions]
 plot[variable=\t,domain=0:2*pi*\pv{nRotations}, samples=90*\pv{nRotations}+1, smooth cycle]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
);
}},
spiro/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1,nRotations/.initial=1}
\begin{frame}[t] 
\frametitle{Spiro`6,-1.5,1`} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.06cm]
\begin{scope}[scale=.68]
\begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2.5cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=.5cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-4.5cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-4cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-3.5cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-3cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2.5cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1.5cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-.5cm]
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}}; 
\end{scope}
\foreach \scl/\p in {.68/1,.56/.6,.44/.4,.32/.2,.2/.1} 
{
(0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=\scl]{spiro={p=\p}}; 
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a white space to the left of the tikzpicture. I am trying to shift the whole drawing to the left to use this unused space.

I tried `\begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm]`  , `\begin{scope}[shift={(180:2cm)}]` and `\tikzset{shift={(-2,0)}}` , but they did not work.

Also is it possible to simplify the code for shifting  `{scope}`.

Comment: A `tikzpicture` is treated like a simple character. Therefore, your picture is aligned on frame like a simple `a`. The problem is that the figure is too large to fit in one frame. You'll have to scale down the figure to show it, or design an smaller one.

Comment: why this drawing is too heavy?

Comment: There is enough space to the left of the frame. If I can shift it to the left a little, it will fit the frame.

Comment: You could change the margins for this slide. In this case, you might be interested in Gonzalo Medina's answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) that you can find following this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160827/204552.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want:

[image]

To do this I have rescaled the `tikzpicture` environment so that the image fits and used `\hspace{-2em}` to move the environment a little to the left.

In terms of simplifying the shifting code, you can use a `\foreach` loop. Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/spiro/.style={code={
\tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}}
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions]
 plot[variable=\t,domain=0:2*pi*\pv{nRotations}, samples=90*\pv{nRotations}+1, smooth cycle]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
);
}},
spiro/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1,nRotations/.initial=1}
\begin{frame}[plain,t]
  \frametitle{Spiro`6,-1.5,1`}
  \hspace*{-2em}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.06cm,scale=0.5]
    \foreach \x in {4.5,4,3.5,3,2.5,2,1.5,1,0.5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5} {
       \begin{scope}[xshift=\x cm]
         (0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=.68]{spiro={p=1}};
       \end{scope}
    }
    \foreach \scl/\p in {.68/1,.56/.6,.44/.4,.32/.2,.2/.1} {
      (0,0) \pic[draw,blue,outer color=blue!80,inner color=blue!10,scale=\scl]{spiro={p=\p}};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; but there is a white space to the left of the tikzpicture, and I want to shift the drawing to use this  unused space.

Comment: @Hany I'll edit

Comment: Thank you very much for your concern.